# CSS Transition With Not Working In Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created a CSS transition which reduces the width of an element. In Chrome and Firefox, this works fine and the width will reduce from 250px to 0 using the transition duration of 0.4s.

On Safari, the width is instantly reduced to 0. Other transitions in the same CSS class work fine, which is why I'm having such a difficulty understanding the problem.

Example site below: (The logo text is what is being reduced to 0 on scroll).

http://mattstest03.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

Code relative to the issue below:

```
<style>
    .smaller-text {
        width: 0;
        position: fixed !important;
        top: 7px;
        margin-top: -15px;
        transition: all 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    }
</style>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var width = window.innerWidth;

        if (width > 1000 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (jQuery('div').offset().top - 10)) {
            jQuery('#logo-text').addClass('smaller-text');
        } else {
            jQuery('#logo-text').removeClass('smaller-text');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Could anybody help me understand this issue? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried applying transition properties to #logo-text and not in the class?

Comment: Sorry for late response. I did try this, thank you. I've abandoned this particular piece of code now.